# How to calibrate the accelerometer of an IMU sensor

Tags: imu, calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new at those calibration stuff.
I need to calibrate the accelerometer which is on imu.
Could you tell me step-by-step how to do it?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11438/how-to-calibrate-the-accelerometer-of-an-imu-sensor./) by [fresh_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/1129/fresh_ros_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the IMU that you're using. Each style of hardware has it's own calibration protocol. Often, manufacturers provide an executable file for calibrating their IMU. Sometimes, people have written their own versions. If you provide the IMU model you're using, I might be able to help you further.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fresh_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/1129/fresh_ros_user/) on 2011-10-06**:
I use "STEVAL-MKI062V2 iNEMO V2".
I will appreciate if you help.
Thanks for your interests.